# Sum between two number

Tags: php, sum

I'm a total newbie when it comes to this so hopefully I can find some answers here.

Looking to sum a generated number by a script with a regular one. Sum of these two numbers will be displayed.

First number value is the one generated by the php script and the second one can be random.

Thank you in advance

Comment: how total will comes?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include the chunk of code you currently have that generates this initial Total number. Also, the chunk of code that receives the input for the second number to add. Assuming these two numbers are stored in a variable, the sum is a simple matter of using a `+` operation on them.

Comment: have a try yourself and we can help you if you go wrong.

Comment: If one of the numbers should be xtracted from a web page then you should post the html code (please only relevant parts) or the url of that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to your php script where showing the total ,  and if there is a variable for the total like this

```
$total = // whatever code is here no matter ;
```

then ,  **after total variable** , do

```
$total = $total+999;
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I had to do a workaround but this example was the key.

Answer (score 1):

Run this code you will see a input, enter second variable then click add button to see your answer

```
<?php
    $result='';
    if(isset($_POST['value2']) && $_POST['value2']!='')
    {
        $result = add(348,$_POST['value2']);
    }
    function add($a,$b)
    {
        $c='';
        $c= $a+$b;
        return $c ;
    }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
    348 + <input name="value2" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['value2'])){ echo $_POST['value2'] ;}?>"  type="text"> = <?php echo $result ;?>
          <input type="submit" value="add">
    </form>
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

$firstVariable = 10 ;
$firstVariable += $secondVariableResult ;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).