# SUM of rows values for all variables

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in mysql and i need to get the SUM for the qty row for the individual product_id and display that using echo.
For example: product_id 65 the total qty would be 3.

```
id   order_id   product_id  qty reference   price   date
5   101   65        1   10012       57  11/03/2021
6   101   65        1   10211       57  11/03/2021
7   101   65        1   10178       57  11/03/2021
8   101   60        2   10266       45  11/03/2021
9   101   60        6   13578       270 12/03/2021
```

I'm currently using the code below which is giving me the results like 1 1 1 (not doing the SUM)
How can i get this acomplished?

```
<td class="text-center">
    <?php foreach ($all_stock as $stock) {
    if ( $stock['product_id'] == $product['id'] ) 
    echo $stock['quantity'];
    }   
?>
</td>
```

My current output is this:

```
Product    Inventory Received   
Laptop    5     
Mouse     26
```

Please note that here the Mouse total should be 8 is display the 2 entries beside each other instead of SUM.

Comment: You are saying that you do not know how to add two numbers in PHP ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum between two number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769856/sum-between-two-number)

Comment: I guess i need to run a query and loop the entire table to find all products that are the same and add them up. This is what i don't know how to do it.